# VSCode not showing syntax colours or option for C after installing extensions

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

[image: Missing syntax options]
I just installed Microsoft's "C/C++" extension and, when that failed to highlight my code, Jeff Hykin's "Better C++ Syntax" for VSCode. I'm on OS X, with `clang` installed. I restarted VSCode.

However, even after adding `"*.c": "c"` to VSCode's "files.associations" block, ".c" files have no colouring, and appear as plain text.

Worse, "C" (or C++) **does not even appear as a language option**.

Closest I can get is to set the language to "Go".

Comment: Could you please attach any sample photo of your error?

Comment: Usually you should only install a single extension in case there are undocumented conflicts.

Comment: I know, but the first failed to show syntax highlighting, so installed the second.